Novel Editor (TipTap Editor) to Pdf Exporter
I am creating a project in which i want to export notes of people(people edit it using novel.sh editor) to a pdf.
I tried using a lot of pdf npm packages but nothing seemed to match my needs. What matched was the browser's save as pdf print option but I don't know how to download it directly without showing the browser's print dialog. Please let me know if there is any way. Thanks
